# angular-carousel ng-click not firing

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-carousel

I have an ng-click action that I want to fire when a user clicks on an item in the angular-carousel. I have tried several different approaches and so far no luck. Also I was able to switch states using `<a ui-sref="state,({params: params})">` but I need to call an encoding function on the `$rootScope` on the parameters (to encode the url of the new state)

HTML (small snippit)

```
  <ui-carousel slides="comsData.adminComs" slides-to-show="slidesToShow" slides-to-scroll="1" initial-slide="1" autoplay="false" dots="true">
    <carousel-item>
      <a data-ng-click="doStuff()">
```

and the controller

```
$scope.doStuff = function() {
  console.log('did stuff');
};
```

right now I'm keeping it simple because as soon as I can get the function to fire the rest is easy

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't a great solution. I just created a new controller and injected it  into the `carousel-item`